# %Invalid interface type and number

Tags: cisco, vlan, interface

I am trying to apply a scenario from the Cisco CCENT book where a 2811 Router uses VLANs. I have applied the network as is in the book inside my Packet Tracer.

Here is the section in the book and next is my implementation and the error I am getting.

```
//book example

Router#config t
Enter configuration commands, one per line. End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#hostname Corp
Corp(config)#enable secret myPassword
Corp(config)#interface vlan 1
Corp(config-if)#description myDescriptionIsAwesome1
Corp(config-if)#ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
Corp(config-if)#no shutdown
Corp(config-if)#int f1/0
Corp(config-if)#description myDescriptionIsAwesome2
Corp(config-if)#no shutdown
Corp(config-if)#int f1/1
Corp(config-if)#description myDescriptionIsAwesome3
Corp(config-if)#no shut


//my implementation in Packet Tracer

Router#config t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#hostname Corp
Corp(config)#enable secret myPassword
Corp(config)#interface vlan 1
Corp(config-if)#description myDescriptionIsAwesome1
Corp(config-if)#ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
Corp(config-if)#no shutdown
Corp(config-if)#
%LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface Vlan1, changed state to up
int f1/0
%Invalid interface type and number
Corp(config)#
```

I get the `%Invalid interface type and number` error.
What can be the reason? Is there anything I should add to the router after adding it in the packet tracer works space? Moreover, how do I create the Virtual Switch once I have set the router? Is it through the GUI or it is automatically done?

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work, you need to add a `HWIC-4ESW` module from the physical modules. Then use `sh int` to see what are the interfaces are named.

The description for it is : The HWIC-4ESW provides four switching ports.